# Reading data from .properties file in Karate 1.4.0 version throws error -> org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: karate.properties

Tags: upgrade, karate

[image]Code Snippet:

- def  stream = read('classpath:karate.properties')
- def props = new java.util.Properties()
- eval props.load(stream)

Above karate script works well with Karate version **0.9.6** but throws below error when try to upgrade the karate version to **1.4.0.**

js failed: **01: read('classpath:karate.properties')**

**org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: karate.properties**

- com.intuit.karate.resource.ResourceUtils.getResource(ResourceUtils.java:126)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.toResource(ScenarioFileReader.java:129)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsStream(ScenarioFileReader.java:99)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFile(ScenarioFileReader.java:76)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.lambda$new$0(ScenarioEngine.java:121)
- .:program(Unnamed:1)

No clue as just version changed from 0.9.6 to 1.4.0
This is a karate maven project.
GitHub link is : https://github.com/hingeashwin/Karate_Upgrade.git

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting a big jump so it is not as simple as " just version changed from 0.9.6 to 1.4.0". Yes, that way of handling properties files is [no longer supported](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#java-api-s-for-maps-and-lists-are-no-longer-visible-within-js-blocks). You will need to do something like [this](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.4.0/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/read-properties.feature):

```
* def stream = karate.readAsStream(path)
* def props = new java.util.Properties()
* props.load(stream)
```

You will need to read all the release notes if you run into further issues.

Comment: Your solution worked well and thanks for the help. It worked well when my  **karate.properties** file is on class path but originally,  it was outside of **src/test/java** and at the same level of pom.xml file but karate does not able to find it. Screenshot is added.