# read property from properties file in Karate and use them in multiple feature files

Tags: properties, karate

I have a class called Utilities.java where I have the method to read properties from the given file path.

```html
public Properties readProperties(String filePath) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            prop.load(fis);
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prop;
    }
```

In Karate-config.js file, I read this java method using the below

```html
var Utilities = Java.type('helper.global.Utilities');
var utils = new Utilities();
var properties = utils.readProperties('src/test/java/Properties.properties');
```

My Properties.properties file is as follows

```html
userName=shilpa
address=223 Baker Street from prop file
```

I want to read the usereName and address Value from the scenario. I am calling them using

```html
Scenario: Add stations
    * def propertyValue = karate.get('properties.userName')
    * print 'Property value: ' + propertyValue
```

But the property value is printed as null. No other error is generated. can you please help?

Comment: please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76765153/143475