# Karate: how to reader karate-config properties in java class

Tags: karate

i have utils java class , and need to import config properties set in karate-config.js

i have tried below code but facing issues with import

```
String configPath = "classpath:src/smoke/resources/karate-config.js";
String configFile = FileUtils.toString(new File(configPath));

String baseUrl = getValueFromConfig(configFile, "baseUrl");
System.out.println("baseUrl: " + baseUrl);
```

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76765153/143475